# VBA comparing two dates

Tags: vba, datetime, compare

I know it sounds like a simple task but I've been trying various approach and still didn't get success yet.

1. I have a big data set with many variables and two of them are of use. First is called "symbol" (aaa,bbb,ccc,etc) and second is "date" (e.g. 2012-05-15 20:00); One symbol corresponds to multiple dates;
2. I wanted to delete some symbols with specific date (e.g., bbb, 2012-05-15) and I have the list of deleting symbols;
3. I was trying to compare the date in dataset and the deleting date in a for loop and to delete the entire row if there equal to each other for specific symbol and that's where the problem is;
4. The code is below:

   ```
   Dim d1 As Date
   d1 = DateSerial(2012, 5, 15) 'This is the deleting date  
   MsgBox (IsDate(d1)) 'This returns true   
   MsgBox (IsDate(DateValue(Cells(4, 9)))) 'This returns true

   For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1  
      If Cells(j,2).Value = "bbb" And (CDate(d1) = DateValue(Cells(j, 9))) Then Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete  
   Next
   ```
5. VBA gave me "type mismatch" error. I also tried If d1 = DateValue(Cells(j,9)) Then Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete but this didn't work either. The screenshot has the value in the cell, when it raises the error.

   [image: The screenshot has the value is in the cell, when it raises the error]

Comment: Have you tried putting a code break in your VBA?  This will allow you to see exactly what the code thinks each value is.  My guess is that DateValue(Cells(j,9) is not a valid date, hence the type mismatch error.

Comment: What's in `Cells(j,9)`?

Comment: @DavidZemens Cells(j,9), i.e. Column(9) has the variable date. I am comparing the deleting date to column 9 and if they match, then delete the entire row.

Comment: D'uh.  What value is in the cell, when it raises the error. Add screesnhot, or update your question please.  I know you *think* it's adate, but without knowing what's actually in there, can't help.

Comment: @DavidZemens I've updated the question. The code MsgBox (IsDate(DateValue(Cells(4, 9)))) returns true which I think means the content of Column I is date variable unless I understand it wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `j` when this error raises?

Comment: j is 7. Cells(j,9) and DateValue(Cells(j,9)) is null (blank in Immediate windown)

Comment: That's your problem :)  can't convert an empty string to a date.

Comment: yeah, I just realized that my Cells(lastRow, 9) is actually empty. Didn't even think about checking the non-emptyness. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're encountering an empty cell which can't be converted to a DateValue.

In the immediate window, try:

`?DateValue("")` and you'll get the same error.

You just need to extend your logic a bit:

```
For j = lastRow To 2 Step -1  
   If Cells(j,2).Value = "bbb" And Not Cells(j,9) = vbNullString And IsDate(Cells(j,9) Then
      If (CDate(d1) = DateValue(Cells(j, 9))) Then Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete  
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this and it works. The only thing I changed is that I put actual dates into the date column, column I (which other commenters noted is perhaps your problem) and I made lastrow a number.

Just ensure that you have dates in column I and last row is a number and you shouldn't get that error

Comment: The code MsgBox (IsDate(DateValue(Cells(4, 9)))) returns true which I think means the content of Column I is date variable unless I understand it wrong.

Comment: is lastrow an integer? I don't see where you set that.

Comment: or try making lastrow = 4 (or whatever date you check with your message box), then put debug.print j inside your loop so you can look at the debugger and figure out where it is tripping up.